# Calling external .h file in Qt

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt, header-files

I wrote some code in Eclipse/ C++ and now I need an user interface for it, so I am creating it in Qt.
I am trying to call the functions that I wrote in Eclipse inside Qt, so I tried many things, like

```
HEADER += /pathToHeaderFile
```

Or

```
INCLUDEPATH += /pathToHeaderFile
```

Or, inside de code,

```
#include "pathToHeaderFile/header.hpp"
```

The first case gives one error: header.hpp: no such file or directory

The second and third give me FIVE multiple definitions of my function.

I don't know what to do! I thought that including the whole path to the include sentence would work, but no success.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Do you need to construct a qmake project file ? If so, then the correct incantation is `HEADERS` (With `S` at the end).

Comment: The second thing I noticed from your snippets is that you are putting only the path in the HEADERS clause. In fact the path to the directory containing your header files should go to `INCLUDEPATH` clause and `HEADERS` should contain a list of your header files (simply their names should be enough).

Comment: I don't know if I will need a qMake project file, but I don't think so... And about HEADERS, yes, it is HEADERS in my file, I just mistyped, sorry! And yes, I used the full path to my files:/pathToHeaderFile/HeaderFile.hpp

Comment: Did you protect you header.hpp file with #defines? This would avoid multiples definition of your functions

Comment: Yes, I did! #ifndef NAME_HPP_ #define NAME_HPP_ ...

Comment: And that's the most weird thing of all! Since when I check the errors (by double clicking over them, inside Qt), they lead me to files that do not have anything to do with those that I wrote!

Comment: If you're in Qt Creator, close all other projects, clean your project, re-run qmake, and then rebuild. I've had this happen when I had two projects open that had very similar file structures. The moc got confused and started building the UI files using the wrong project.

Comment: @user2547658 than there is maybe something wrong with `Qt` itself (or its tools). I experienced a very similar thing. In code I had a macro named `allways_inline` and during compilation I was getting tons of warnings about its redefinition pointing me at `qgenericatomic.h`, which by coincidence internally uses macro with the same name (it is undefined at the end of that header). Putting `#ifndef allways_inline` around my macro did not help. I made this annoying warning go away by playing with the order of include directives. I am using `Qt 5.0.2` and `QtCreator 2.7.0` and `MingW`.

Comment: YES! The problem is with the moc files! I found some info around the forum about moc files, but none of them really apply to my problem, since I am not defining any signal/slot nor I am including any moc files to my main file (nor any other file!). I am very new to QT and I just need this interface to test some functions I created, so I am not sure if I am runing qmake or not... I don't think so, since I just ask to build and compile the code.

Comment: I am not just getting warnings, I getting errors! I can't even run the code!

Comment: Just found out! That is odd!!!
.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082318/how-to-find-the-multiple-definitions-of-a-function